# Apply plugin from rootproject file in kotlin dsl gradle file

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Currently I applying a root project plugin in App Level gradle file using groovy. Here is the code for it:

```
apply from : rootProject . file ("jacoco.gradle")
```

Now I want to change gradle file from groovy to kotlin dsl. Can you please guide me, how can I aplly this plugin in app level kts gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
apply(from = rootProject.file("jacoco.gradle"))
```